# The method called in action component of redux is not working

Tags: reactjs, redux, action, dispatch, redux-reducers

```
const getProducts = () => async (dispatch) => { 
    try { 
           const data = await fetch("http://localhost:8005/getproducts", 
           {  method: "GET", 
              headers: {     
                 "Content-Type": "application/json"
               }
           });
           const res = await data.json();
           console.log(res);
           dispatch({ type: "SUCCESS_GET_PRODUCTS", payload: res });
    } catch (error) {
           dispatch({ type: "FAIL_GET_PRODUCTS", payload: error.response });
     }
}
export default getProducts;
```

this method is not working which is in action.js file
and is being called from here.

```
const { products } = useSelector(state => state.getProReducer);
console.log(products)
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProducts());
});

}
```

it was working previously but when i restart the server it stopped working.

Comment: Is the piece of code where you aren't passing an empty array of dependencies identical to your real code or just a typo in this post?

Comment: You said it *worked*, so what does your `res` and `products` print now?

Comment: I’m guessing you didn’t setup redux thunk. Did you?

Comment: i want the 'products' to print the data which i am sending from the database but it does not print anything, also i do have installed and used 'redux thunk'